# W3C Endpoint & Exchange Implementations

Tags: web-services, apache-camel

I'm new web services (and, specifically, Java web services) and have seen the terms **endpoint** and **exchange** sprinkled throughout various frameworks. I did some deductive reasoning and eventually found the first term, endpoint, defined in the W3C docs as a binding between a protocol and and URL.

What I have not been able to find is a generic W3C term for "exchange" as it is used by the Camel framework and in other places.

Does anybody know what these so-called "exchanges" are, what is being exchanged (both directions), and where I could find some literature about their theoretical/abstract definitions?

Thanks for any help here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Camel, an [Exchange](http://camel.apache.org/exchange.html) is the container holding the information during the entire routing of a [Message](http://camel.apache.org/message.html) received by a Consumer.  Its comprised on properties, an IN message and an OUT message.  Each [message](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Message.html) consists of headers, a body and attachments.  The IN message carries the request message and the IN or OUT can be used to carry the response message (depending on the [Processors](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html) being used).

See the Exchange class documentation for more information: http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html